# Example of Vue.js and Three.js in a code snippet

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Is it possible to use Vue.js with Three.js library in a code snippet?

If yes, how should the Three.js be loaded and called in the snippet?

I tried to load it with:

```
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js">`
```

And then called it with:

```
this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
      });
```

But the code snippet didn't seem to load the library as my object (a cube) didn't show up.

Comment: When you go to the snippet edit screen, and you add a library, it adds the cdn library to the html of the snippet. I would imagine Threejs is added the same way.  Have you tried to do this?

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica Yes I have, but it's not enough. I need to import it somehow in VueJS code.

Comment: What do you mean by import in Vuejs? Do you mean in SFCs?

Comment: I mean; why can't you just do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48208630/785241)?

Comment: This belongs on the main [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site not SO Meta.

Comment: @Dave It really doesn't. It's about "the software that powers Stack Overflow", and is therefore on-topic here. What makes it a bad question is its lack of research and attempt to solve. What makes it closeable is its broadness.

Comment: @DevonDahon I didn't downvote.  Thanks for the assumption.  Definitely not going to upvote now.  Responses like yours are exactly why people don't comment in the first place.  Every time this happens, I wonder why I still try to help people.

Comment: @DevonDahon That isn't related to Vuejs specifically; it's an es6 feature; the ability to import libraries in that syntax.  That the feature is used in SFCs does not make it vue-centric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js">` to load the library in the code snippet HTML window and call it using `THREE.whatever` in the JavaScript window.

Comment: can you please refer to a snippet in StackOverflow where this approach has worked for `three.js` and `vue.js` together, thanks in advance.